# Which elements are affected for a particular css class

Tags: css, dom, visual-studio-2012, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to know exactly which elements (DOM) are affected for a particular CSS class, using some development tools such as Chrome Dev Tools, Firebug or inside IDE Visual Studio???

Comment: Web Developer Toolbar has an Outline > Outline Custom Elements feature and you can enter stuff like `.your-class` or `#your-id` but I believe the feature is only available on Firefox's version, not Chrome's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery (or similar JavaScript frameworks), you could paste the CSS rule (whether class or not) into a selector in the JS console for the development tools of the browser you are using. It will then evaluate all matches.

Here is an example of usage on this site:

[image: Example using the Stack Overflow site]